# how to redirect the page from controller according to condition in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have been working for authentication for each $http request and url changes. Therefore i have implemented peace of codes for url changing authentication as bellows

```
/** login-controller.js file **/

//when the form is submitted
$scope.submit = function() {
    console.log("enter login submit");
    $scope.submitted = true;
    if (!$scope.loginForm.$invalid) {
        $scope.login($scope.credentials);
    } else {
        $scope.error = true;
        $scope.error_des = '';
        return;
    }
};

// if a session exists for current user (page was refreshed)
// log him in again
if ($window.sessionStorage["userInfo"]) {
        var credentials = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage["userInfo"]);
        $scope.login(credentials);
};

//Performs the login function, by sending a request to the server with the Auth service
$scope.login = function(credentials) {

    $scope.error = false;
    Auth.login(credentials, function(user) {
        //success function
        $mdDialog.hide();
        $state.go("admin-panel.default.home");
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("error");
        $scope.error_des = err.msg;
        $scope.error = true;
    });
};
```

Everything is working as i expected but while reloding the same page it'l always redirect to home(http://localhost:3000/#/home).i know that it happens because of

```
$state.go("admin-panel.default.home");
```

trouble is , i want to redirect the page according to login way let'say if user login via form submitted which will be redirected to $state.go("admin-panel.default.home");
As well if user login via session exists for current user which will be redirected to $state.go("admin-panel.default."+**$current_page**);

how to achieve it? please help me????

Answer (score 0):

```
If form submit : var formsubmitted = true;
if login via session : formsubmitted = false
 and while routing you can check condition 
if(formsubmitted == true)
   $state.go("admin-panel.default.home");
else
$state.go("admin-panel.default."+$current_page);
//to get current page path  you can use $location.path();
```